# Trouble Serializing To JSON Using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, javascriptserializer

I'm having some trouble serializing an object to a JSON string using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.  Whenever I try to do it, my strings are automatically html encoded.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  I'd really like to avoid using an external library if possible (code is for .NET 4).  Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myHtml = "<div class=\"blueBackground\">This is a really cool div:)</div>";
        int someOtherValue = 5;

        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string jsonObj = jsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyClass
        {
            StringProperty = myHtml,
            IntProperty = someOtherValue
        });

        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It outputs the string

> {"StringProperty":"\u003cdiv class=\"blueBackground\"\u003eThis is a
>   really cool div:)\u003c/div\u003e","IntProperty":5}

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strings are not HTML encoded. They are javascript encoded. JSON is intended to be read by javascript interpreters and your output is perfectly valid javascript as seen in [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DgFkR/). It's valid JSON and any standard JSON deserializer will be able to understand this output and deserialize it back to the original string. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: Wow, thanks Darin:)  I had no idea there even was such a thing.