# asp.net MVC display encoding character

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, unicode, javascriptserializer

In my project, I serialize an object by JavaScriptSerializer.  Then, I want to display in my cshtml page. Unfortunately, the result is not what I want.

My controller is very simple:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                Name = "yubaolee <yubaolee>",
            };

            return View((object) new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(person));
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name;
    }
```

I try some methods like:

```
@Model
<br />
js document.write:
<script>
    document.write('@Model');
</script>
```

the output is：

[image]

Two results are not what I want. I want to get:

```
{"Name":"yubaolee <yubaolee>"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet package which contains the static class `JsonConvert` that you can use in your controller this way:

`object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
return View(json);`

Comment: Thank  for your answer. I Know Newtonsoft.Json can dispose it. But , Forgive my willfulness, I just want to know how to display properly in web by this way

Comment: This might be helpful: [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390819/trouble-serializing-to-json-using-javascriptserializer) :)